# admob banner error in xcode after unity export

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29prz.jpg) of the error I am getting. If anyone can help solve this it would be greatly appreciated. In unity there were no errors but after I exported it for IOS and then tried to build it on iphone I am getting these 3 errors.

My code:

```
+ (GADAdSize)adaptiveAdSizeForWidth:(CGFloat)width orientation:(GADUBannerOrientation)orientation { 
  switch (orientation) { 
    case kGADUBannerOrientationCurrent: 
      return GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(width); 
    case kGADUBannerOrientationLandscape: 
      return GADLandscapeAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(width); 
    case kGADUBannerOrientationPortrait: 
      return GADPortraitAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(width); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code on the question and specify your problem

Comment: + (GADAdSize)adaptiveAdSizeForWidth:(CGFloat)width orientation:(GADUBannerOrientation)orientation {
  switch (orientation) {
    case kGADUBannerOrientationCurrent:
      return GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(width);
    case kGADUBannerOrientationLandscape:
      return GADLandscapeAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(width);
    case kGADUBannerOrientationPortrait:
      return GADPortraitAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(width);
  }
}